# Custom appender in other project of same solution

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I have a (working) Appender that is located in a different project of the same solution.

I can access that Appender from ONE other project within that solution, but all others fail displaying an error in the log:

> log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [AzureAppender] of type [my.Backend.AzureAppender].
>
> Reported error follows. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type [my.Backend.AzureAppender]. Tried assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a] and all loaded assemblies

References to my.Backend exist.

The Appender content follows:

```
<appender name="AzureAppender" type="my.Backend.AzureAppender">
  <FileName>web.log</FileName>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms [%t] %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dll is not already loaded, then you may need to change your type to include the name of the dll.

```
<appender name="AzureAppender" type="my.Backend.AzureAppender, mydllName">
```

This should tell log4net to load the dll named mydllName.dll and then look for the type called my.Backend.AzureAppender inside that.

If that fails you can try adding the complete AssemblyQualifiedName for the type.

Comment: I did try to setup dll binding, to look for dll binding issues (fusion log), ...
Aligned web project and appender project to use same version of log4nett.dll + adding the dll file name fixed it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy the dll which contains the my.Backend.AzureAppender into your bin folder of your project. I'm sure it is missing. The cause is that there are no direct references in your code to this dll, so it is not copied to your output bin dir.

Comment: I added references to my.Backend (and the .dll is also in the bin-directory)